# Getting TexLive installation to work

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, ubuntu

In the [launchpad website](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521) it is mentioned that the version in the repositories is hopelessly outdated (by two years, even in the oncoming october release). I was trying to install TeXLive 2011 (in Ubuntu) and succesfully followed [all the instructions](http://justbloodywork.blogspot.com/search/label/ktikz) given in the linked blog.

However, when I make a tex file containing the header

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through, intersections,decorations.text}
```

I think it is not able to load the package. I get the error message

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibrary'.
```

I am wondering this was probably because of the final statement in the aforementioned blog

> That should be that. Remember that ktikz needs to load up the PGF
>   packages you want to use. Common ones for me are loaded as follows:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through, intersections,decorations.text, decorations.pathreplacing}
```

I didn't really understand what this meant, so I presumed he meant to add this as the header to the latex file, as normal. Apparently, that is not the case.

Could someone tell me how to get my installation to work? How do I load up the packages I want to use?

Additional info: I added the following files to my .bashrc (and even .profile)

```
cat >> ./.bashrc << "EOF"
PATH= /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
export PATH MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$INFOPATH 
export MANPATH export INFOPATH
EOF
```

When I do a `which pdflatex` I get `/usr/bin/pdflatex` while it should tell me something like `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`
`

---

Disclaimer: This code is not mine. I am just testing to see if TikZ works.

```
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,through, intersections,decorations.text}


\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3]
\def\myangle{117};
\clip (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\node [blue, name path=blue_circle,draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\draw [black, fill] (A) circle (1pt) node [below] {\tiny centre};
\draw [red, dashed] (A) -- (B);
\path [name path=radius, rotate=\myangle] (A) -- ++(1.5,0);
\draw [red, ->] ($(A)+(0.5,0)$) arc (0:\myangle:0.5cm);
\path [decorate,decoration={raise=-5pt, text along path, text={|\tiny|angle ||}, text align=center, text color=red, reverse path}](0.5,0) arc (0:\myangle:0.5cm);
\draw [name intersections={of=blue_circle and radius, by=C}] [orange, ->] (A) --  (C) node [pos=0.7, sloped, above] {\tiny radius};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `ktikz` (which is a TikZ editor), or are you trying to use TikZ in a normal LaTeX document? In the latter case, have you loaded TikZ using `\usepackage{tikz}` before `\usetikzlibrary{...}`?

Comment: @Jake yes, I loaded tikz. I am editing the example I working with into my question.

Comment: @Jake also, I am using a normal text editor, Vi and not ktikz

Comment: What machine are you using?  Is it a 64bit machine or a 32bit?  Can you post the result of `ls /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin`?

Comment: Also, did you log out and log back in again after installing?  You would need to do _something_ like that to force bash to read the new `.bashrc` to reset the path.

Comment: The problem is that you are still using the version of tex that came with Ubuntu.  I get exactly the same error when I disable TeXLive2011 and revert to the system version of TeX.  The actual form of the error is due to the space in the list of libraries (early versions of PGF did not allow spaces, I surmise).  If you remove the space, it complains about missing the `intersections` library.  If there were no obvious errors with the installation, and the paths are correct for your architecture, then my best guess is that you didn't log out and log back in again!

Comment: @Andrew I did restart for the path to reset. The result of the command you posted is the folder named `x86_64-linux` (64 bit Lucid Lynx on a 64 bit machine) ). I also hadn't bothered with the default 2009 version I had installed from the repositories as in the [official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#TeX%20Live) it was written that installing the latest version does not interfere with any other package. But I still removed them just now, to give the whole thing another try.

Comment: Crosspost http://askubuntu.com/questions/57924/getting-texlive-installation-to-work

Comment: @N.N I deleted my post at AskUbuntu as I didn't get any answers there.

Comment: The result of `which pdflatex` says that _something_ isn't quite right, though.  Can you post the result of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @yayu : For my installation I chose the "portable" option and nothing TeX related went in to `\usr\local`. Installing normally (not portable) put it `\usr\local`. It runs fine now! You might want to check that you have a TeX tree in `\usr\local`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same frustrations as you, yayu, with respect to the pitiful state of TexLive on Ubuntu. By forcing people to use Google for solutions rather than 
rely on Ubuntu to actually maintain their packages in a timely fashion mistakes are inevitable. In my case, similar problems were caused by my TeX tree not being installed in the correct location. I had chosen a "portable" installation intending to be queried as to where I would like to install it. However, that never happened. Why? I have no idea. I followed Andrew Stacey's advice of trying to install a non-portable version. I did and it now works fine on your example and some others I checked. Perhaps this explains your problem, too.

I was told to make sure my umask was 022 first. The TL2011 documentation says something about making sure it "is sufficiently permissive, for instance, umask 002". I found Ubuntu default is umask 022 so there is nothing to change. I did a "sudo texhash" just to make sure the info was up to date.

The final challenge was with respect to changing the PATH/MANPATH. The TL2011 documentation tells you "the file to edit might be $HOME/.profile". You're on your own again, so I Googled, found various conflicting information, made changes, and nothing worked. I still don't know what the problem is but I did find that TeXworks allows me to specifically configure the path. Start TeXworks, go to the Edit tab, select Preferences and under the Typesetting tab you can use the "+" key to specify the path to your TeX tree. I used the "-" key to remove other options. For me that meant adding `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux` but since I am using a 64-bit machine, that last item for you might differ. Using TeXworks runs TL2011, the other editors run TL2009. Not a complete solution, but I'm happy. I will look into finding a distro that does a better job keeping TeX packages up to date.

How do you install packages on Ubuntu? It's supposed to be through Synaptic Package manager, but since the "current" Ubuntu packages are so out of date this isn't what you want. The second option is the package manager tlmgr if you can find some way to get it onto Ubuntu. The third option is to install the packages manually which means downloading the files to your computer and then moving them (via a sudo command) to the appropriate area of the TeX tree and a texhash command to update the TeX tree. A major headache! I'll leave you to Google for those annoying details although I'll point out a helpful link for getting style files onto Ubuntu [here](http://blog.irrepupavel.com/2007/02/installing-latex-style-files-sty-on.html). Installing TeXLive 2011 to `/usr/local` bypasses Ubuntu and will give you a system which is reasonably up to date.

Answer (score 8):

1. Uninstall TeXlive from the Ubuntu repositories:

   `sudo apt-get remove texlive`

   `sudo apt-get autoremove`
2. Install a dummy package so Ubuntu will never ever try to install TeXlive again. See http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla ("Vanilla TeX Live on Debian")
3. Make sure perl-tk and perl-doc are installed:

   `sudo apt-get install perl-tk perl-doc`
4. There is no need to modify .bashrc or anything else. When starting the TeXlive manager GUI (with `cd /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux` and `sudo tlmgr --gui`) you can set symbolic links to `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`.
5. See if the correct TeXlive installation will be used

   `pdflatex`

   should print something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)`

Comment: I get tlmgr command not found on doing this. Also on step 2 there was a problem in the last step, but I think I wont worry about that at the moment.

Comment: Regarding step 2: Since the instructions are for Debian, you have to modify them for Ubuntu a bit. Just take a look which commands are marked `# as root`. These have to be called with `sudo` prefaced.

Comment: I did that :) I actually did not understand "you should change some information in the file..." so I just copied the example they linked.

Comment: That's ok, I did it just the same way.

Comment: See also: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=10920&start=20#p44096  Please note that there is no option "Create symlinks to standard directories" in the TL2011 installer, but one can easily do this in the TeXlive Manager GUI after installation.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 aren't technically necessary; so long as the TL2011 binaries are earlier in the path than the ones installed by Ubuntu, the Ubuntu packages will simply be ignored.  As TL installs under `/usr/local` it won't get overwritten by any Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 4):

TeX Live 2011 should work without having to uninstall the Ubuntu packages, as Andrew states in his comment, if the user's PATH environment is correct.

If you run `env` at a command prompt its output includes your current PATH. The path to your TeX Live 2011 installation *must* be before  `/usr/bin`. For example, my path is "`PATH=/home/mas/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/mas/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin: ..`." (I have TeX Live 2011 installed in my own user directory, not under `/usr/local`) and I can run the sample above without error. If `/usr/bin` is before the TeX Live path I get the same error as you.

A further check is to use the `which` command. For example, again using one of my own machines:

```
mas@ents:~$ which tlmgr
/home/mas/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
mas@ents:~$ which pdftex
/home/mas/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex
```

but some tools are in other directories:

```
mas@ents:~$ which texworks
/usr/bin/texworks
mas@ents:~$ which LaTeXTidy
/home/mas/bin/LaTeXTidy
```

Finally, the test Alex suggested in his answer:

```
mas@ents:~$ pdftex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**^C
mas@ents:~$
```

FYI, the lines added at the end of my .profile are:

```
PATH=/home/mas/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/home/mas/texlive/2011/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/home/mas/texlive/2011/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH
```

but these are, of course, specific to where I have installed TeX Live 2011 and the machine's architecture.

You also need to check that any IDE or other tool you use that has its own path settings in its configuration is set appropriately. For example, TeXworks has the path to use configured internally, see under 
Edit->Preferences->Typesetting.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the instructions and code that yayu has been trying to follow.  In the main I have absolutely no idea what I am doing.

Yayu, as a number of much cleverer people than me have identified, you need the texlive PATH to be at the beginning of your %PATH.  The commands I wrote to edit the .bashrc file are supposed to achieve that, but looking at the text you have pasted in above something has gone wrong:

```
export PATH MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$MANPATH
```

That should be two lines.  There should be a line break after the first PATH.  So it should look like this:

```
export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$MANPATH
```

What the commands are supposed to do are to take whatever the system variable PATH is, and to reset it.  The "export" command then dumps the changed variable back out into the system at large.  The problem is that the two commands there are getting smooshed together, so they are probably not working.

The commands should look like this:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc << "EOF"
PATH= /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH
export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:$INFOPATH 
export MANPATH
export INFOPATH
EOF
```

As I said on the blog though, I still have PATH related problems doing this.  it works fine if I run commands from the terminal, but if I run them from icons it gets lost again.

If you remember to run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then it should work without rebooting.