# Can I download CTAN packages from the command-line? (Ubuntu)

Tags: packages, ubuntu, ctan

I'm reading [this](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4DF35DB8.7050606@espci.fr&forum_name=pgf-users), where one of the respondents says to "get a package from CTAN". There are no installation instructions in [the package mentioned](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

I've installed `texlive-full` and use the long-term support version of Ubuntu precisely so I won't have to deal with this stuff, so everything will "just work".

Is there a command I can run from the terminal, like `ctan-install` or `latex-install`, that will find the packages I need, update them, etc.?

(`sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't show that `texlive-full` needs updating.)

**update:** Thank you for the help, everyone. I think this is going to work (eventually). However as I keep downloading `iso`'s, the `synaptic` package for `texlive-full`, and `install-tl`, my hard drive is now close to full with all of these `TeX` libraries! What should I delete after this is all over, and how? (I tried to remove the `texlive-full` meta-package in Synaptic and it said it would remove `teXmacs` as well.) Also: how am I ever going to keep this up to date and working with other programs I may install in the future?

Comment: Have you tried `tlmgr update --all`? [`tlmgr`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) is the TeX Live manager and would download & install packages (from a default or given repository) from the command line.

Comment: @Werner: `tlmgr` doesn't work with the TeXLive package of the  repository.

Comment: This is related to the long-standing issue that Ubuntu uses an old version of TeX Live for 'stability', and so you are much better off installing TeX Live directly from TUG so that you can use `tlmgr` for installations. (The TL team sort out sorting out CTAN packages - it's not as simple as 'download and put in the right place'.)

Comment: @Werner `sudo apt-get install tlmgr` nor `apropos tlmgr` didn't find anything.

Comment: @Joseph: sadly, I don't think stability is the reason really, rather that packaging TeXLive as deb packages is a huge mess nobody wants to do once a year...

Comment: @laotzu if you're going to use recent packages, I'd really recommend you drop the packaged version of TeXLive and install it with `install-tl`.

Comment: @Raphink How do I drop the packaged version and install it with `install-tl`?

Comment: @Joseph Wright How do I get `tlmgr`?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/getting-texlive-installation-to-work

Comment: @laotzu: Follow the instructions over at http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another solution is to download TeX Live 2011 from [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html).  After having installed it, and having performed the post-installation step, you can then use `tlmgr` to list the packages that are available for download or have been updated as follows:

```
sudo -i tlmgr update --list
```

You can also use the following command, for example, to get all the packages available for download/update:

```
sudo -i tlmgr update --all
```

To select a particular package for download/update, type the following command:

```
sudo -i tlmgr update <package-name>
```

This requires you to know the name of the package you want to download/update.

Alternatively, you may run the `tlmgr` in GUI mode by typing the following command:

```
sudo -i tlmgr --gui
```

This will allow you to select the packages that you want to install/update/remove.

Note that, in order to run `tlmgr` in GUI mode, you will need to install `perl-tk`.

P.S. Yes, I am using Ubuntu, and have not had a problem thus far....

P.P.S. The post installation step requires that you add the path to your TeXLive 2011 binaries in $PATH.  To do this for all users, create a file called `zzz-texlive.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/`uname -i`-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
unset TEXINPUTS
unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

Note that you will have to be logged in as `root` to do this.  If you can't log in as `root`, create the file using the following command:

```
sudo vi zzz-texlive.sh
```

`vi` is a text editor that will allow you to create the file.  You may, however, use other editors if `vi` is not your thing.  Once you set up the paths correctly, and reboot your system, you can then run `tlmgr` as indicated above.

Note that the above post-installation solution was proposed by @Herbert [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/setting-the-path-to-textlive-installation-round-2).

Comment: I installed Tex Live 2011 from the `.iso` but I still don't have `tlmgr`.

Comment: @Lao - <code>tlmgr</code> should come with TeXLive 2011.  Have you set the paths correctly, as part of the post installation step?  FYI - I will modify my answer to include this.

Comment: I think so. The post-installation step was to append `PATH=/usr/x/y/z/:$path` and more to the end of `~/.bashrc`, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.  Try typing 'which tlmgr' at the system prompt.  What does that give you?

Comment: BTW - You also need to capitalize $path (i.e. $PATH).

Comment: `which tlmgr` returns nothing. Thanks for the `$PATH` advice -- looking at `~/.bashrc` I guess I had already done it that way.

Comment: OK, it seems like *tlmgr* is not installed.  As a sanity check, though, cd to your root directory and type the following command at the system prompt: *find . -name "tlmgr" -print*

This will tell you for certain whether or not *tlmgr* is installed.

Comment: Now that I've added that `/etc/profile.d/zzz-texlive.sh` I get the following message on starting a new bash window: `bash: export: /downloads/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/:/home/bill/dev/:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games=/usr/share/fslint/fslint/:/downloads/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/:/home/bill/dev/:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:....': not a valid identifier`

Comment: `find` found `./usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr
`

Comment: So, it is installed!  This is the path that you need to put in your `zzz-texlive.sh` file.  As for the message that you are getting, in the `zzz-texlive.sh` script, change `'uname -i'` for `i386`.  This should solve your problem.

Comment: Bill, thank you for your continued efforts. The first line of `/etc/profile.d/zzz-texlive.sh` now reads `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH` but I am getting `bash: export: /downloads/sage-4.7.1...-Linux/...:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games=/usr/share/fslint/fslint/:/downloads/sage-4.7.1...-Linux/:/home/.../dev/:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/:.../usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games': not a valid identifier`

Comment: @Lao - Did you reboot your system after you made the change?  That might solve your problem.  Otherwise, you may refer this problem to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Bill, thanks for your help. The problem was that, amidst all of these different advice pages, I had edited `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile.d/zzz-texlive.sh` . The user `~/.bashrc` ended in this: http://pastie.org/2516101 and when I deleted that appendage the problem went away.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the problem.  I hope that `tlmgr` is working for you now.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply download it using [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html), but this is off topic:

```
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/<package path+packagename.zip>
```

This command saves the package in the current working folder. You can change the target with

```
wget -O $HOME/Download http://mirror.ctan.org/<package path+packagename.zip>
```

Once downloaded, you can unpack the archive `.zip` with [unzip](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/unzip/).

Now you must copy the package (files) in a search path of TeXLive. I recommend a local folder. You can find the local folder with:

```
kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'
```

Normally it is saved in:

```
/home/<user>/texmf
```

Note: TEXMFHOME, like all trees, must be organized according to the [TDS](http://tug.org/tds/), or files may not be found. For details see: [TexLive Directories](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-270003.2.3)

Lastly: Sometimes it is necessary to call `mktexlsr` to update TeX's filename database (FNDB).

Comment: But this just downloads the entire package (as a packed `.zip`). Could you add some detail about unpacking it in either the local directory, or migrating it to your distribution folder (and running `texhash`)?

Comment: Ah. I didn't know `kpsexpand`. I had found the word `texmf` in `/usr/share/texmf/` so I was putting `LyX` / `Sweave` stuff in there (that's what started this whole multi-day installation process: [trying to get `Sweave` to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354222/sweave-lyx-fig-t-in-sweave)). Did I maybe cause a problem by putting files there?

Comment: @LaoTzu: Private files should always been locate in the home directory.  You can install such programs in `/usr`. For details see: [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure). With the command `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` you didn't find the folder `/usr/share/texmf/ definitely. But I think you should ask such question on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Right, I hadn't heard of `kpsexpand` until today. I was just looking around in the file system. I probably did `ls -R / | grep texmf`. I've looked at that Wikipedia article before and it doesn't make sense to me. Yes, this question is kind of a hybrid between (3) fora. Are `TeX` libraries "private"?

Comment: @LaoTzu: If the package author provided a TDS ZIP file then it should be under `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib/<name>.tds.zip`. Simply unzip it over your TEXMF tree.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer How do I unzip it over my TEXMF tree?

Comment: @LaoTzu: You simply use an unzip software and choose as target the base directory of your TEXMF folder. I would use your local per-user TEXMF folder which is normally under `~/texmf` for Linux/Unix OSs. Try the mentioned `kpsexpand '$TEXMFHOME'` command to find it on your installation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, contrary to the blog instructions I found, it would have been easier to do a `net-install` of `texlive` as per http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html, rather than torrenting an `iso`, mounting the `iso`, and more instructions after that.

There seem to be fewer commands to run and fewer ways to get lost with the `net-install`.

Once the installation is finished, TeX Live will prompt you to edit `~/.bashrc`, *mutatis mutandi.* Do that, then run `mktexlsr` and/or `texhash`. (I'm not sure what either command *really* does, but they seem to be important—and running them doesn't seem to muck anything up.)

Finally, you will have the `CTAN` command-line package management program **tlmgr**. [This page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#examples) lists several commands you should run with `tlmgr`, such as updating self and updating all.

If things go amiss, try `reinstall`ing or updating packages with `tlmgr` and running `texhash` again.

Answer (score -1):

1. `wget http://mirror.ctan.org/package-path+packagename.zip`
2. `unzip packagename.zip`
3. `mkdir /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/packagename`
4. `sudo cp /path/to/packagename/packagename.sty /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/packagename`
5. `sudo mktexlsr`
6. Be happy.

Tested on Ubuntu.