# TeXLive no longer find path

Tags: root, kpsewhich

All of a sudden my `TeXLive` is no longer find any path; it was working fine. Now, it gives me when I compile any latex file:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt: kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFROOT failed, aborting early.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexfmt line 25.
I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!
```

The output from `texconfig conf` is:

```
[wyousef@archlinux ~]$ texconfig conf
=========================== version information ==========================

==================== binaries found by searching $PATH ===================
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/wyousef/Downloads/AAProgramsAA/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/wyousef/Downloads/AAProgramsAA/anaconda3/bin
kpsewhich: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
updmap: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap
fmtutil: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil
texconfig: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/texconfig
tex: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/tex
pdftex: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex
mktexpk: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexpk
dvips: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/dvips
dvipdfmx: /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/dvipdfmx

=========================== active config files ==========================
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf.cnf
config.ps: not found
fmtutil.cnf: not found
mktex.cnf: not found
pdftexconfig.tex: not found
updmap.cfg: not found
XDvi: not found

============================= font map files =============================
psfonts.map: 
pdftex.map: 
ps2pk.map: 

=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist
TEXMFDIST=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist
TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
TEXMFVAR=
TEXMFCONFIG=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
VARTEXFONTS=
TEXMF=
SYSTEXMF=
TEXMFDBS=
WEB2C=
TEXPSHEADERS=
TEXCONFIG=
ENCFONTS=
TEXFONTMAPS=

==== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here) ====
TEXMFCNF=/usr/local/texlive/2018
```

## EDIT01:

I already had tried `mktexlsr` and `sudo mktexlsr`; same problem. Moreover, `sudo texconfig conf` gives me complete path names!!

## EIDT02:

This problem is not caused by anything unusual that I did. It is the daily update I do for pacman and texlive:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
sudo tlmgr update --all
sudo tlmgr update --self
```

## EDIT03 (Problem Solved):

From the suggestion of the comments below the problem was solved by the following. I installed first `perl-tk` to be able to run the `gui` of `tlmgr`; then I ran it using`sudo tlmgr --gui`. Then, I did all possible rebuilding from the `Actions` menu NOT by installing or re-installing any package; i.e.,
1. Update filenames database
2. Rebuild all formats
3. Update font map database
4. Handle symlinks in system dirs: Update symbolic links

I am not sure, of course, which step was responsible for the resolution.

Comment: Guess some fixes may not work well if paths are upset but odd that your getting some feedback so looks like you may need to try a few "rebuild" tasks e.g. can you run texhash or mktexlsr and fmtutil-user --byfmt latex

Comment: I already had tried `mktexlsr` with no success. Please, read my EDIT above

Comment: I think those that know your platform will need to know the platform and exactly what command line you are trying e.g. I note that in some platform configurations a simple command such as **Latex Test** may not work (although it does redirect to PdfTeX on mine and I presume yours did before?) It may also help to identify any recent change that could be related and that good old chestnut that you did restart after making any significant change to system variables (eg shell startup scripts)

Comment: I did nothing except the routine texlive update I do daily;  `sudo tlmgr -update --all`

Comment: It is possible that a hiccup developed during that last --self (personally since I am a windows user would prefer the perl interface) e.g. sudo tlmgr --gui to check / trigger some of the settings there. From experience and the observation of others a common comment is that in such cases it is wise to logoff / reboot first in order to check latest current status of a rogue start-up when environmental settings are misbehaving.

Comment: I note from PATH listing above multiple similar entries which suggests potential for loading conflicting locations for part sequences (however since identical that should just add to some slowdown / confusion rather than any misloading) HOWEVER one set of env vars could be blanking another. In the tlmgr --gui you could try run Actions menu > "Rebuild all formats" which would be similar to command line **sudo fmtutil-sys --all** that should (re)create all missing format files, watch for feedback / read any summary (I think --force option is for compatibility but worth trying as a last resort)

Comment: @KJO Good idea. What happens after `tlmgr gui`? Can you (Waleed) get the formats etc. rebuilt?

Comment: Thanks so much; this solved the problem. Please, see my EDIT03 above for details.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst TeX has been traditionally managed over a very long history from the command line the increasing variety of commands can result in the need for simpler management of  option combinations.

Both MiKTeX and Tex Live have GUI package managers that can also run key maintenance tasks in the background and some of those tasks can be done with and without super user or administrator privilege which may require dual entry.

For TeX Live the Perl-TK component needs to be installed if it was not added by TL-install (should have been done by install for windows users).

When you enter `tlmgr --gui` or `sudo tlmgr --gui` you will have access to all the maintenance tasks together under one user level.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reinstall texlive core

```
sudo pacman -Sy texlive-core
```

Comment: I installed tex from CTAN not from packman

Comment: I think this link will help you  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27993/can-i-download-ctan-packages-from-the-command-line-ubuntu

Comment: I think this is unrelated, since tlmgr cannot update anymore. It is frozen for 2019 release preparation.

Comment: You will use **tlmgr** to reinstall lost package `sudo -i tlmgr --gui` and choose the wanted package to install.